# Scrapyd spiders are finished but they are still being shown as Running on WebUI as well as listjobs.json

Tags: google-cloud-run, scrapyd, scrapyd-deploy

I have deployed Scrapyd as docker conainter on Google CloudRun. On my local, when I am running container, everything is working fine. But, when I am deploying same container on Google CloudRun, Spider jobs are not removed from Running queue. Though Jobs are finished but they are not being removed from Queue. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [Github](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/issues/213) :

Close the webdriver in spider close function as follows:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # webkit driver
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=PHANTOMJS, service_log_path='/tmp/ghostdriver.log')
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(1)
        self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(3)
        
    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(NewsDuowanSpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_closed, signal=scrapy.signals.spider_closed)
        return spider


    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        spider.logger.info('Spider closed: %s', spider.name)
        spider.driver.quit()
```

For more information, you can refer to the [link](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/issues/21) and [documentation](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: But, I am not using webdriver here.

Comment: have a look on link :https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/issues/21 Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

i meet the same issue, when deployed scrapyd on cloud run. The reason may be the sub  proccessor exited , but processEnded method not invoked, when
add processExited method to kill zhe slot, the issue solved!

i temply solve it by using my own launcher:

```
class Launcher(Service):

name = 'launcher'

def __init__(self, config, app):
    self.processes = {}
    self.finished = app.getComponent(IJobStorage)
    self.max_proc = self._get_max_proc(config)
    self.runner = config.get('runner', 'scrapyd.runner')
    self.app = app

def startService(self):
    for slot in range(self.max_proc):
        self._wait_for_project(slot)
    log.msg(
        format=
        'Scrapyd %(version)s started: max_proc=%(max_proc)r, runner=%(runner)r',
        version=__version__,
        max_proc=self.max_proc,
        runner=self.runner,
        system='Launcher')

def _wait_for_project(self, slot):
    poller = self.app.getComponent(IPoller)
    poller.next().addCallback(self._spawn_process, slot)

def _spawn_process(self, message, slot):
    msg = native_stringify_dict(message, keys_only=False)
    project = msg['_project']
    args = [sys.executable, '-m', self.runner, 'crawl']
    args += get_crawl_args(msg)
    e = self.app.getComponent(IEnvironment)
    env = e.get_environment(msg, slot)
    env = native_stringify_dict(env, keys_only=False)
    pp = ScrapyProcessProtocol(slot, project, msg['_spider'], \
        msg['_job'], env)
    pp.deferred.addBoth(self._process_finished, slot)
    reactor.spawnProcess(pp, sys.executable, args=args, env=env)
    self.processes[slot] = pp

def _process_finished(self, _, slot):
    process = self.processes.pop(slot)
    process.end_time = datetime.now()
    self.finished.add(process)
    self._wait_for_project(slot)

def _get_max_proc(self, config):
    max_proc = config.getint('max_proc', 0)
    if not max_proc:
        try:
            cpus = cpu_count()
        except NotImplementedError:
            cpus = 1
        max_proc = cpus * config.getint('max_proc_per_cpu', 4)
    return max_proc


class ScrapyProcessProtocol(protocol.ProcessProtocol):

def __init__(self, slot, project, spider, job, env):
    self.slot = slot
    self.pid = None
    self.project = project
    self.spider = spider
    self.job = job
    self.start_time = datetime.now()
    self.end_time = None
    self.env = env
    self.logfile = env.get('SCRAPY_LOG_FILE')
    self.itemsfile = env.get('SCRAPY_FEED_URI')
    self.deferred = defer.Deferred()

def outReceived(self, data):
    log.msg(data.rstrip(), system="Launcher,%d/stdout" % self.pid)

def errReceived(self, data):
    log.msg(data.rstrip(), system="Launcher,%d/stderr" % self.pid)

def connectionMade(self):
    self.pid = self.transport.pid
    self.log("Process started: ")

def processEnded(self, status):
    if isinstance(status.value, error.ProcessDone):
        self.log("Process finished: ")
    else:
        self.log("Process died: exitstatus=%r " % status.value.exitCode)
    self.deferred.callback(self)
# on cloud run processEnded not invoked, but processExited
def processExited(self, status):
    self.processEnded(status)

def log(self, action):
    fmt = '%(action)s project=%(project)r spider=%(spider)r job=%(job)r pid=%(pid)r log=%(log)r items=%(items)r'
    log.msg(format=fmt, action=action, project=self.project, spider=self.spider,
            job=self.job, pid=self.pid, log=self.logfile, items=self.itemsfile)
```

finally , you should change the scrapyd.conf file：

```
 launcher    ={your launcher  module}.Launcher
```